# Software, plugin or tool similar to Flaticon's seamless pattern maker?

Tags: software-recommendation, patterns

I have been having a lot of fun with [Flaticon's pattern maker](http://pattern.flaticon.com), but it only lets you use their icons. I would love to use a similar tool to use my own icons and designs.

I realise there are lots of ways to achieve a seamless pattern, but the above mentioned tool is so effortless. I can't imagine there aren't any similar tools, plugins or software out there, but I can't find any.

**So my question is, are there any easy seamless pattern making tools out there?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Illustrator's pattern editor is (assuming you're familiar with Illustrator) easy to work with and offers a lot more control...

It's as simple as placing the icons (or whatever) you want to use on the artboard, then selecting them and going to *Object → Pattern → Make*. That will create a pattern swatch and open up the pattern editor with that pattern.

You can edit the artwork exactly as you would outside of the pattern editor; change colors, transform etc. You can add or remove more artwork without leaving the editor with no problem too. The editor also gives you a lot more control over tile size and alignment:

[image]

---

- [**How to create and edit patterns in Illustrator - Adobe Support**](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/create-edit-patterns.html)